# Как принять значения POST после запятой для дальнейшей работы

Tags: post, php, sql, mysql

```
    $qwe =("SELECT * FROM  ведомость");
                    $sq = mysql_query($qwe) or die(mysql_error());  
                    $ro = mysql_fetch_array ($sq);
                    echo  "<select name='conved'>"."<option
    >"."Название"."</option>";
                    do   
                    {
echo 'ведомость:<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($ro['дисциплина'].','.$ro['группа']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($ro['дисциплина'].','.$ro['группа']). '</option>';
                    }
                    while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($sq));
                    echo "</select>";
```

происходит выборка  например :(мат лаб, 4343)
необходимо  получить значение группы

Comment: А если в названии дисциплины будет запятая?

Может стоит на смену дисциплины навесить обработчик, который будет писать в скрытое поле нужную группу?

Либо (что лучше) в value писать id записи.

Comment: Можно заменять запятую на "&#44" в названии дисциплины, тогда при explode она не будет затрагиваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

```
$res = explode(',', $_POST['conved'])[1];
```